# Geting olny first element of a comboBox item like 5x5 in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have this line: `int WinSize = Int32.Parse(comboBoxWinSize.Text);`

The comboBox includes items like 3x3,5x5,7x7... My aim is to declare the WinSize as the first element of a comboBox item. For example, WinSize should be 5, if comboBox item is 5x5.

How can I get only first element of axa?

Answer (score 0):

1. First split the string by seprator ('x') in your case
2. From the array you got after split, get the first element

   ```
   string first = comboBoxWinSize.Text.Split(new char{'x'})[0]; 
   int WinSize = Int32.Parse(first);
   ```

Comment: It works but I don't understand the [0]. What is the task of this?

Comment: Split, function returns an `array` of all splitted strings found. So by calling [0] you get the first element, as was requested by you.

Comment: sigara if you are not sure about something google the method and read as well as try to understand the examples that are shown for the `Split()` Method